# Why is this illegal in strict mode?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, strict, use-strict

Yeah, yeah, I know, strict mode ain't around yet, but really, I'm planning for the future...

So, why is this:

```
$('#'+ $(this).attr('id').replace('control-', 'legend-')).fadeIn();
```

... not allowed in ES5 Strict mode?

Or am I misinterpreting? JSLint:

```
Problem at line 516 character 18: Strict violation.
```

Could it be a little more verbose, I wonder...?

EDIT:

To avoid confusion, here's more of the original code:

```
function displayLegend() {
    $('#'+ $(this).attr('id').replace('control-', 'legend-')).fadeIn();
}
```

Comment: Just curious, what does `$('#'+ this.id.replace('control-', 'legend-')).fadeIn();` do?

Comment: Wow, a 100k person... never seen one of these before. It's a bit complicated out of context... This is for a userscript, Manga ChapterReader, you can find it out there. Basically, I have matching HTML elements which have the same id with different prefixes. When you hover a control, the description (legend) fades in. I found it's pretty nifty to be able to add a control using predefined patterns.

Comment: I don't know strict mode well enough to give a coherent answer, but it appears to have something to do with using `this` outside of what looks like a method. If I change the code to `'use strict';var foo = {};foo.bar = function () {$('#'+ $(this).attr('id').replace('control-', 'legend-')).fadeIn();}` then it passes the strict test on JSLint.

Comment: It could be related to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode#this_in_functions_%28.0aUnimplemented.0a_as_of_Firefox4.0b8pre%29 (and it could also be a bug in JSLint, it is possible that it would only fail if the function was called in the context of `window` and that as you are using it as an event handler — that will never happen. All this is speculation on my part though.

Comment: @David: Doesn't it have something to do with the part of the spec I quoted in my answer, whatever it really means?

Comment: @Marcel — looks like the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some trial-and-error of this code in [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/)

```
"use strict";
var that="dd";
function $(x){return x;}

$('#'+ $(this).attr('id').replace('control-', 'legend-')).fadeIn();
$(this);
```

shows me what's wrong: you're using `this` as a parameter. Changing both `this`es to `that`s doesn't trigger the error.

As [the specification](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Annex_C.htm) says:

> If **this** is evaluated within strict mode code, then the **this** value is not coerced to an object. A **this** value of **null** or **undefined** is not converted to the global object and primitive values are not converted to wrapper objects. *The **this** value passed via a function call (including calls made using **Function.prototype.apply** and **Function.prototype.call**) do not coerce the passed **this** value to an object* ([10.4.3](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_10.htm#Section_10.4.3), [11.1.1](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_11.htm#Section_11.1.1), [15.3.4.3](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_15.htm#Section_15.3.4.3), [15.3.4.4](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_15.htm#Section_15.3.4.4)). *[my emphasis]*

As John Resig [writes](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/#js-7),

> Finally, a long-standing (and very
>   annoying) bug has been resolved: Cases
>   where null or undefined is coerced
>   into becoming the global object.
>   Strict mode now prevents this from
>   happening and throws an exception
>   instead.
>
> ```
> (function(){ ... }).call( null ); // Exception
> ```

As you showed, using your line of code inside a function declaration throws an error in JSLint, whereas using it inside a function expression doesn't. It looks like JSLint erroneously parses the function declaration, sees `this`, that's still undefined at that moment, and throws an exception.

At this point, I think I have to quote [Juriy Zaytsev (‘kangax’)](http://perfectionkills.com/onloadfunction-considered-harmful/#does_it_really_matter):

> ### Does it really matter?
>
> It’s good to understand that **strict mode is not a requirement**, but is
>   merely an option. It is there to
>   provide stricter rules for those who
>   need it, and are willing to cope with
>   (and enjoy) consequences.

---

**Update:** At last I found an explanation. If you read [this thread](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/jslint_com/messages/927?threaded=1&m=e&var=1&tidx=1), especially from message #1512 onwards, you'll read that

> The point of ES5/strict is to prohibit
>   leaking of the global object,
>   something that ES3 does promiscuously.
>   ES5/strict does some of its work
>   dynamically, and some of its work
>   statically. JSLint does all of its
>   work statically, so it must be even
>   more restrictive in order to best help
>   you get your program right. *[Douglas Crockford in #1553]*

I have to admit that he has a valid point here: if your goal is to avoid global namespace pollution, you shouldn't use function declarations, but function expressions inside a private namespace, anyway. But I agree with others in the mentioned thread that the error message should be more explicit (and probably throw a warning on encountering a function declaration).

Comment: What??? But I need `this`, not `that`! The line's inside a function, triggered by an event! How am I supposed to get the element clicked without `this`?

Comment: Does it really matter? Yup, for me it does. That's just how I am :)

Comment: @passcod – Yeah, I understand, I'm the same. ;)

Comment: After further questioning, it is JSLint's normal behaviour... something to do with guidelines or conventions, I guess. Great Answer!

Answer (score 3):

Following what David Dorward said, I found something that passes JSLint's test. This is downright strange as to why it's doing that.

Before: (see question)

After:

```
var displayLegend = function () {
    $('#'+ $(this).attr('id').replace('control-', 'legend-')).fadeIn();
};
```

EDIT:

I asked Douglas Crockford:

> JSLint only allows this in strict mode
>   in functions that are obviously
>   intended to be called as methods. So
>   write
>
> ```
> object.property = function () {
>     ... this ...
> };
> ```

This confirms what it says in the spec, except it's much clearer!

Comment: Ah, now you're using a *function expression*, instead of a *function declaration*; the former is parsed at run-time, the latter before the script is executed (and `this` probably still is unset, in the eyes of JSLint).

Comment: @MarcelKorpel, thanks for the comment. It clarified the whole issue a bit more.